# Ajax. Передача спецсимвола из php

Tags: php, css, ajax

Ситуация такая: есть форма, которую заполняет пользователь, данные обрабатываются в php-скрипте, затем возвращается ответ. При определенном ответе, мне нужно изменить псевдоэлемент after одного из блоков (поместить в его поле content часть данных, возвращаемых php-скриптом). Проблема в следующем: скрипт может возвращать код спецсимвола (здесь, для примера я буду использовать \27A4). И когда я делал все это без ajax'a все работало хорошо, я просто передавал переменную в стиль. Но теперь код символа не преображается, собственно, в сам символ.

PHP-скрипт:

```
$the_path_trigger = "\27A4";
$result = [
    "chat_answer" => $chat_answer, //В возвращаемом массиве есть еще и этот элемент, но это не имеет значения
    "the_path_trigger" => $the_path_trigger
];
echo json_encode($result);
```

В css, чтобы менять content у псевдоэлемента after я сделал следующее:

```
content: attr(data-content);
```

В скрипте на странице, при успешной обработке следующее:

```
success: function(response) {
    var result = JSON.parse(response);
    $(".nav-toggle-2").attr("data-content", result.the_path_trigger);
},
```

Итак, это не работает. У меня получилось сделать так, чтобы поле content выглядело так, как нужно, следующим способом:

```
$(".nav-toggle-2").attr("data-content", "\u27A4"); //Именно добавление 'u' спасло ситуацию
```

Но, когда я пытаюсь сделать это в php

```
$the_path_trigger = "\u27A4";
```

то в поле контент просто выводится сам код, а не символ

То же самое, когда пытаюсь пойти таким способом:

```
$the_path_trigger = urlencode("\u27A4");

$(".nav-toggle-2").attr("data-content", decodeURI(result.the_path_trigger));
```

Comment: у вас там этих кодов куча что ли? или пара только? я к тому, чтобы переключать контент добавляя классы к элементу, а не передавать этот контент с сервера

Comment: заэкранировать там надо слэш в php-коде `\\u27A4`, наверное.

Comment: @teran Ну не так, чтобы совсем куча. Но все же хотелось бы сделать все без переключения классов, если это вообще возможно. Дело в том, что это ведь работает, проблема лишь в передаче кода символа.

Comment: @teran со слешем то же самое получается- выводится код символа